# How can I show my label/id when using \cmpd from the chemnum package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, chemnum, showkeys, showlabels

I am using the `chemnum` package of Clemens Niederberger to label my chemical compounds. Now I have quite a large amount of compounds and sometimes it would be helpful to see the label in the document without looking for the corresponding line of code (of course only during preparation of the manuscript). A similar feature comes with the `showkeys` package, but of course that works only for "real" labels.

I created an sample image to clarify, what I am talking about. 
Is it possible, to redefine `\cmpd` with an option to print the label?

[image]

Edit:

I am now aware of the `show-keys` option of the package, however this fails when using `chemnum` inside of `tikz` environments. `\setchemnum{show-keys=ref}` did not help, because it does not show the label when the compound appears the first time.

My workaround so far is to redefine `cmpd` to run like `\cmpdshowref{compound}\cmpd{compound}`. If there is a smarter way to do this, I am happy to read about it.

Edit 2 (added now a MWE):

• The `show-keys` option runs into errors, when the first appearance of a compound is inside a `tikz` environment.

• Apparently, the `show-keys` option runs into errors when the label contains an underscore (e.g. `compound_2`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum,tikz}
\setchemnum{show-keys}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor.

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor.

\tikz \node[fill=yellow] at (0,0) {Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor.};

\tikz \node[fill=yellow] at (0,0) {Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar2} dolor.}; % <- fails

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar_2} dolor. % <- fails

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There very likely *is* a smarter way but as I said: it is hard if not impossible to say more without a minimal working example.

Comment: I edited my question and added an MWE.

Comment: I extended my answer to cover your additional questions…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to original question:**

`chemnum` has this built-in, see section 12 *Debugging Information* of the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{show-keys}% <<< this is what you're looking for

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor

\end{document}
```

[image]

The key of a newly defined label is printed to the margin while a call referencing an existing label is printed inline.

**Answer to edited question:**

The two “failure” cases you mention have different causes:

1. ```
   \tikz \node[fill=yellow] at (0,0) {Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar2} dolor.};
   ```

   This leads to an error because the default definition of `\cmpdshowdef` uses a `\marginpar`. Since this is quite similar to a float you cannot use it inside a box (tikz node). A solution is to redefine it using the `\marginnote` command from the `\marginnote` package. The needed redefinitions are shown in the `chemnum` manual section 12 on page 25:

   ```
   \usepackage{marginnote}
   \renewcommand*\cmpdshowdef[1]{%
     \marginnote{\fbox{\normalfont\ttfamily#1}}%
   }
   \renewcommand*\subcmpdshowdef[2]{%
     \marginnote{\fbox{\normalfont\ttfamily#2 (#1)}}%
   }
   ```
2. ```
   Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar_2} dolor.
   ```

   This fails due to the same reason you cannot use the underscore character `_` in normal text and gives the expected error: `Missing $ inserted.`. This happens when trying to print the label text.  `\detokenize` can help here:

   ```
   \renewcommand*\cmpdshowdef[1]{%
     \marginnote{\fbox{\normalfont\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}}%
   }
   \renewcommand*\subcmpdshowdef[2]{%
     \marginnote{\fbox{\normalfont\ttfamily\detokenize{#2 (#1)}}}%
   }
   ```

The full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum,tikz}
\setchemnum{show-keys}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*\cmpdshowdef[1]{%
  \marginnote{\fbox{\normalfont\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}}%
}
\renewcommand*\subcmpdshowdef[2]{%
  \marginnote{\fbox{\normalfont\ttfamily\detokenize{#2 (#1)}}}%
}


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor.

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor.

\bigskip

\tikz \node[fill=yellow] at (0,0) {Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar} dolor.};

\bigskip

\tikz \node[fill=yellow] at (0,0) {Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar2} dolor.}; % <- fails

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum \cmpd{foobar_2} dolor. % <- fails 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I browsed the manual of chemnum but somehow I did not find this feature.
However, this solution does not work in my case, because I use chemnum inside of tikz environments and the option `show-keys` fails here. But due to your manual, I redefined `\cmpd{compound}` to `\cmpdshowref{compound}\cmpd{compound}`. Right now, I don't see any troubles, but this does not mean anything. Is there a smarter way to define this?

Comment: @es560 there will still be an error when using the underscore and the label is referenced. I'll add something later or tomorrow how to cover that case (depending on when I have time…)